# id is not present in validate() and ListSerializer's update() Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm learning and new to Django Rest Framework and I'm having an issue in serializer validations and ListSerializer update method.

I have an APIView class which handles the put request. I just wanted to have a custom validation and so I've overridden validate method in the serializer class.

From postman I'm sending a JSON data to this APIView Class.

Sample JASON data:

```
[
{
            "id": 1,
            "ip": "10.1.1.1",
            "host_name": "hostname 1"
},
{
            "id": 2,
            "ip": "10.1.1.2",
            "host_name": "hostname 2"
}
]
```

When I receive the data and do serializer.is_valid() it passes the flow to the overridden validate function. But in there when I check for the attrs argument, I get all the fields except the id. The key and value for id are not present. It shows None.

The same issue occurred to me when I was trying to override the update method in ListSerializer.

when I tried the below code in the ListSerializer's update method,

```
data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data}
```

I got an error saying KeyError 'id'.

It seems it's not accepting id field and I'm not sure why! Please, someone explain this to me if I'm wrong anywhere.

Serializer class

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import NoAccessDetails


class NoAccessDetailsListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def update(self, instance, validated_data)

        data_mapping = {data.id: data for data in instance}

        #Here I'm getting KeyError ID
        validated_data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data}

        return 


class NoAccessDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = NoAccessDetails
        list_serializer_class = NoAccessDetailsListSerializer
        fields = ("id", "ip", "host_name")

    def validate(self, data):

        id_val = data.get('id')
        ip = data.get('ip')
        host_name = data.get('host_name')

        #here the id value is None
        print('id val {} '.format(id_val))
        return data
```

Comment: Could you add your serializer code please?

Comment: I have added the serializer code. I've not added complete code for ListSerializer's update method since I was getting KeyError

Comment: @MrName I have added the serializer code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, the issue is that you do not see the `id` field inside of `validated_data`. If so, I believe this is intentional in the framework:

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2320

Basically, the `id` field is `read_only` by default. Let me know if you have questions that are not answered by Tom's response to that issue.

EDIT: Also feel free to share the higher level use case (what you are planning on doing with the ID inside of validation), and maybe we can offer alternative approaches.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. Even in the Django Rest Framework documentation, it is mentioned over there. 

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update. 

The default implicitly-generated id field is marked as read_only. This causes it to be removed on updates. Once you declare it explicitly, it will be available in the list serializer's update method.

Thanks, @MrName for helping me. :)